# The way to visualize discrete variables

Tags: python, r, visualization

I have a table as follows:

|  | Sample1 | Sample 2 | Sample 3 | Sample 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Attribute 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Attribute 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Attribute 3 | low | medium | high | none |

I have tried to use heatmap but it is not exactly what I want.
For the entries with a value of 0 or None,
I want to leave them blank.
Since the variables are not numerical here,
I am wondering whether there are better ways to visualize them.

Now I only use open-source tools like R and Python,
but advice using other tools will also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not a matter of the tool and not a programming problem. As is a heatmap might be fine. But it's your data and your analysis: How should we know what you want to show and what's the goal of your analysis?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am sorry that I did not ask in a good way. My goal is to show whether a certain sample has a certain attribute.    In other words, to show a matrix with only 0 or 1 entries.  I have seen some papers using the existence of a circle to show it.  Maybe I should show the figure I want to imitate and ask how I can reproduce it.  I have just started to use stack overflow, I am not sure if I can add a figure in the reply.